# Java - Processing: Cannot call other classes in enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

I'm attempting to use Java's (Processing) enhanced for-loop in my game, however it seems I'm unable to call other classes in the the other loops. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);

  rLife = new ArrayList<RegLife>();

  for (int i = 0; i < rLife.size(); i++) {
    rLife.add(new RegLife(width/2, height/2));
  }

  lLives = new ArrayList<largeLife>();

  for (int i = 0; i < lLives.size(); i++) {
    lLives.add(new largeLife(width/2, height/2));
  }
}


void draw() {
  background(255);

  for (largeLife l : lLives) {
    l.seek(r);

    l.update();
    l.display();
  }
  for (RegLife r : rLife) {
    r.stayWithin();

    r.update();
    r.walk();
    r.withinRadius(r);
    r.display();
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is in

```
for (largeLife l : lLives) {
     l.seek(r);
```

I get the error message "the variable 'r' does not exist"
Yet I called it in the class

```
 void seek(RegLife r) {
    PVector desired = PVector.sub(r.posi,posi);
    desired.setMag(speed);

    PVector steer = PVector.sub(desired,velo);
    applyForce(steer);

  }
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve]. Your code doesn't show everything that is relevant to form an adequate answer. The problem is simple, there is no `r` variable known at that location in the code and you knew that already. To convince you we would need to see the whole class.

Comment: Where do you think that the `r` comes from that you're using on the line with `l.seek(r);`?

Comment: Note that the error message doesn't refer to the method, inside the `seek` method the variable `r` is known, as it is a parameter of the method. But at the location where you call it `l.seek(r)` the variable `r` is **unknown**. Why do you think it would be known? Is there some `r` in the class, for example as member variable?

Comment: I assumed that `r` came from ` for (RegLife r : rLife)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, a for-block has a well-defined scope that begins and ends with its `{}`s for single-/multi-line blocks and for exactly one statement on for-blocks which omit the `{}`s.

Therefore, in `draw` you attempt to use a variable that truly does not exist. `r`, in your example, is in scope only here:

```
  for (RegLife r : rLife) {
      // use r here all you want.
  }
```

However, you cannot use it here:

```
  for (largeLife l : lLives) {
      // r does not exist here..
      l.seek(r);
  }
```

Depending on what you're trying to do you could nest them like here:

```
  for (RegLife r : rLife) {
      // use r here all you want.
      for (largeLife l : lLives) {
          // and use it here too..
          // if that makes sense.
          l.seek(r);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much it works now! I'm not the smartest coder and I knew it was an easy fix but I just couldn't wrap my head around a solution.

Comment: @Cencu If this question helped you, please mark it as correct. And in the future, please try to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

well.. yea. You have no variable "r" in that draw method.

Comment: I didn't down vote it but it's not accurate. There is an `r` in `draw` but it's not in scope where they use it. I think a down vote is appropriate since it's a rewording of the error they're already looking for a **solution** for.

Comment: When I change the variable `r` to something else, the error message tells me it expects parameters `RegLife`. However even when I change the variable to `RegLife`, I still get an error message.